# Spring Roo: common library generation using entities

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have a web services project which uses Spring Roo.

TestEntityController.java

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseMessage newEntity(
        @RequestBody final TestEntity entity) {

    entity.persist();
}
```

TestEntity.java

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
@RooJson
public class TestEntity {
    // ...
}
```

The web service takes as input a JSON string that it binds to the entity object in the Spring roo project. I then have a client project which POSTs to the web service these JSON files. I was wondering if there is a way to export the entity classes into a "commons" or "client" library that client projects can use to easily create the JSON string by reusing the entity classes.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must create a multi-module project: project-api, project-impl, project-web, etc

Create your entities, interfaces and all the artifacts that you want share in "project-api" and distribute the rest of project artifacts in the other modules.

Comment: Does Roo know not to add all the Jpa entity methods to the project-api  classes for public distribution, yet add them for internal consumption?

Comment: Public distribution or internal consumption is your decission, Roo cannot know that. Roo will create entities, etc in the module you are when the related command was executed.